# Endpoint returning only new and updated records

Tags: architecture, api, api-design

let me state some items.

- I have this endpoint that returns a list of objects, and I would like to return only the changed ones.
- I have an App calling this endpoint that caches this list, and today it refresh the whole list every time the endpoint is called.

I would like to manage, to return to apps only the records, that have been changed, however some user might have the cache more updated than another one.
Lets make an example

I have 4 fruits and its respective last modified date

```
Apple - 2019/09/15
Orange - 2019/09/10
Peach - 2019/09/20
Melon - 2019/09/18
```

And 1 Users

Michael

Michael has opened his app by the date of 2019/09/19

The returned records would be:

```
Apple - 2019/09/15
Orange - 2019/09/10
Melon - 2019/09/18
```

Then, "Melon" got an update, so my list became

```
Apple - 2019/09/15
Orange - 2019/09/10
Peach - 2019/09/20
Melon - 2019/09/26
```

On next call to API, by the date of 2019/09/26, the return must be

```
Peach - 2019/09/20
Melon - 2019/09/26
```

At least thats what I thought about.
So I have two questions:

1. Is that a good approach to enhance my API performance?
2. How must I design this API?

Comment: It sounds like you're attempting to add state within a service, which is generally a "don't do that" type of thing. A skip/ take model might work where the client provides a token of some sort to indicate the last known record. I would focus a lot more on the requirements that make you think this is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a query parameter (e.g. `modified_after`) that the client can use to fetch only items that have changed since the last time.

The modification time should be part of the item's data, so the client can just take the youngest modification time of its cached items to select everything new.

Comment: I've had this idea, however it has a problem, How would I know if an item that did not return, is deleted or not modified?

Comment: That's a valid concern, I did not think about it. Off the top of my head I would suggest keeping a separate endpoint that answers deletions since a given time, but that requires that you keep such a list on the server, and you need some mechanism to prune this list and return the information to the client that some of his cached data might be stale and he should discard it all when he asks for items deleted before the pruning date. It also feels somewhat wrong as this wouldn't be a business resource but a purely technical one.